# What is the easiest way to import Vue.js to a typescript file?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

This is the file of interest: `import Vue from 'vue';`

Currently it is marked as red from the IDE because no steps have been taken to define `'vue'`

How to integrate without using webpack or other tools?

(as a first approach we need to take the minimum amount of steps since this is basically a django app that is going to use just a little bit of Vue.js)

Comment: the Vue package comes with typings for Typescript, so I don't see what should be necessary. Maybe your ide doesn't pick up the typings - VSCode does for me.

Answer (score 0):

Install the package via npm/yarn:

```
npm install --save-dev vue
```

Answer (score -1):

Look at Vue docs
[Vue Typescript](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html)

Comment: Thanks @Aleksandar. The docs refer to creating a new project from scratch: `vue create my-project-name`. This is not what we want to do at all here. The other way around, we want to take the minimum amount of steps to have Vuejs and Typescript working in an old project

Comment: Than you should be able to to it like this `import * as Vue from 'vue';`
Basically you import all from Vue lib and put it in Vue variable. It will stop throwing error and you can now use Vue as it its.